# Variable x must be of size [5 1]. It is currently of size [5 5]. Check where the variable is assigned a value

Tags: matlab

Consider a linear system equation 
The matrix for this i typed in matlab as ,

```
D =  [-3,-18,1,-47,3;2,4,2,11,1;1,4,3,10,8;1,32,4,69,5;7,-40,5,-101,-1];
b = [11;3;7;-17;1];
```

The problem says; for Dx=b, commute solution for x by inverting MATRIX D. I

I did `x = b./inv(D)`, however i get an error stating "Variable x must be of size [5 1]. It is currently of size [5 5]. Check where the variable is assigned a value"

Please help

Comment: This is a basic linear algebra issue, not a programming issue. You need to multiply both sides of the equation **on the left** with `inv(D)`. Matrix multiplication doesn’t compute. That leads to `x=inv(D)*b`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a linear algebra issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: Matlab have a special operator for that: `x=D\b` where `\` is the mldivide operator. I would recommand to use `\` instead of `x=ind(D)*b` since the result will be more robust